# Why doesn't my checkmark stay on my card?

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I am trying **to create a checkmark for my menu** when I click on it however as soon as I release the click it disappears immediately. I am a beginner and I am looking for help to resolve this problem.

```html
<button class="menu">
    <div class="description">
        <h4>Fricassée d'escargots</h4>
        <p>
            Au piment d'Espelette
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_price">
        <div class="menu_check"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</button>
```

Below is `scss` code.

```css
.menu
{
    background-color: $color_3;
    width: 634px;
    height: 72px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    .description
    {
        margin-top: -13px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 572px;
        height: 42px;
    }

    .menu_price
    {
        display: flex;
        padding-left: 94%;
    }

    .menu_check
    {
        display: flex;
        width: 59px;
        height: 73px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: -65px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        background-color: $anim-color;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: margin-right 1s;
    }

    .menu_check::after
    {
        content: "";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        padding: .3125rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #99e2d0;
        font-size: .9375rem;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
    }

    &:active .menu_check
    {
        margin-right: 0px;
        animation: slide 1s;
    }

    @keyframes slide
    {
        0%
        {
            margin-right: -65px;
        }

        100%
        {
            margin-right: 0;
            transform: rotate(360);
        }

        0%
        {
            margin-right: -65px;
        }
    }

}
```

I would like the checkmark to be persistent and it is removed after clicking on it again.

https://codepen.io/Hiura_s/pen/jOdOYGe codepen for my code

Comment: Hey Hiura, welcome to stackoverflow :) You can create working code-snippets in your questions, this way it's easier to answer and understand your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Code-Snipped.

You will need Javascript with this, since this is more logic than css can handle.

All the js code does is if the button is clicked, it checkes if the `.menu-check div` already has the `.menu-active` class. If it does, it removes it, if it doesn't, it adds it.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuCheck = document.querySelector('.menu_check');

menu.onclick = () => {
  if (menuCheck.classList.contains('menu-active')) {
    menuCheck.classList.remove('menu-active');
  } else {
    menuCheck.classList.add('menu-active');
  }
}
```

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 634px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .description {
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 572px;
  height: 42px;
}

.menu .menu_price {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 94%;
}

.menu .menu_check {
  display: flex;
  width: 59px;
  height: 73px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: -65px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: #000;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-right 1s;
}

.menu .menu_check::after {
  content: "";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  padding: 0.3125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #99e2d0;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-active {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Box_menu1">
  <button class="menu">
    <div class="description">
      <h4>Fricassée d'escargots</h4>
      <p>Au piment d'Espelette</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_price">
      <div class="menu_check"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```